# Convert Recursive Directory Listing to MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I need to list all files/folders in a given parent folder, and dump it out to mysql.

So far I have:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dir = '/home/kevinpirnie/www';

function dirToArray( $dir ) {
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, array(".", "..")))  {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            } else {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$res = dirToArray($dir);

echo '<hr />';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

What I am stuck on is how I can assign `ID`'s to the directories, and then associate them with their parent `ID`'s.

Right now, this code sort of does what I need it to, I just need to be able to convert it to mysql insert statements, yet keep the associative structure, and I am braindead from a long long week of work.

In the end, I am looking to have a table structure similar to:

FileID, FolderID, ParentFolderID, FileName

How can I do this?

Comment: You would need to insert your parents first, so you can get their Ids in return and set those Ids as the parentId for the subdirectories. If you used an ORM like Doctrine it would do it for you.

Comment: because those are my rquirements for this

Comment: If you aren't overly fussy about database structure you can store the actual directory as the "key" value. Then, from a starting point, you just query all entries that have a key starting with the "key" of the starting point with no join required.

Comment: What's the difference between Folder and ParentFolder? Can you give some example, please? What's the schema of your db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code a little. Now for every directory,

index 0 point to directory index

index 1 point to parent directory index

index 2,3,....n points to files

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dir = '/home/kevinpirnie/www';

$GLOBALS['I'] = 0; // root folder given index 0

function dirToArray( $dir , $parent) {
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, array(".", "..")))  {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){

                $result[$value] = [++$GLOBALS['I']]; // add folder index
                $result[$value][] = $parent; // add parent folder index

                $result[$value][] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value, $GLOBALS['I']);
            } else {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$res = dirToArray($dir, $GLOBALS['I']);

echo '<hr />';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
echo '</pre>';
```

You can now insert the data into mysql tables directly using a similar recursive loop (if you do not want to use mysql auto generated id)

If you want to use auto generated mysql id, you should do insertion in two passes. In first pass insert the folder data and get the id from mysql insert id function. Then create an associative array map

$array_map[$current_folder_id] = mysqli_insert_id()

Then update this id in the second recursive pass

Answer (score 4):

try something like this:

```
function dirToDb($res, $parentId = 0)
{
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value))  {
            $db->exec("insert into table (path, parentId) VALUES (?, ?)", [$key, $parentId]);
            dirToDb($value, $db->fetch("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"));
        } else {
            $db->exec("insert into table (path, parentId) VALUES (?, ?)", [$value, $parentId]);
        }
    }
}

$res = dirToArray($dir);

dirToDb($res);
```

Comment: how to do it as an array as I posted?

Comment: What do you mean? You do first call your method dirToArray() and the result has to be passed to dirToDb()

Comment: I mean set ID's in it

Comment: You should use AUTOINCREMENT, MySQL will take care of the rest then

Comment: @Kevin, I think you are asking for ID's even before inserting into the database which is possible if only one user will connect to the database at a time

Comment: If I consider that point of view, if you want the IDs to be declared by PHP you need something like a global counter, which increases the ID before every INSERT without using an AUTOINCREMENT. But I would not recommend that.

Comment: That is correct @manian   I do want ID's before the insert.   Only one person will connect, and this script in fact will only ever be run from cli

Comment: You can use UUID. There's lots of libraries and some mysql functions

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to insert folder names too as records into the DB, otherwise you wont get parent ID. But, in your result the folder names are missing as record items. I modified your code with assumption that you don't need the result as array but the SQL statement only.

```
<?php
$qry = array();
$result = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(FileID) as lastid FROM YOUR-TABLE-NAME-HERE");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$id = $row['lastid'];
function dirToSql($dir, $parent) {
  global $qry;
  global $id;
  $result = array();
  $cdir = scandir($dir);
  foreach($cdir as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, array('.', '..'))) {
        $id++;
        $qry[] = "('".$id."', '".$dir."', '".$parent."', '".$value."')";
        if(is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . $value)) {
            dirToSql($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . $value, $id);
        }
    }
  }
  return $qry;
}

$dir = '/home/kevinpirnie/www';
$sql = dirToSql($dir, 0);

//Here is your SQL Statement
echo $qry = "INSERT INTO YOUR-TABLE-NAME-HERE (`FileID`, `FolderID`, `ParentFolderID`, `FileName`) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql);
```

You can optimize the code & the query if needed

Answer (score 0):

Every row in your Mysql directory table has three columns -

Directory Id, Directory name, parent id

For each insert the parent id will specify the parent of current directory in a row. For the Root directory parent id is 0

Answer (score 0):

A really useful way to structure your database is with nested sets. Joomla uses this for things like article categories. These can be infinitely nested under one another.

[enter link description here](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets)